# Detectar evento ondrag jquery

Tags: html, jquery, javascript-eventos

Estou trabalhando com drag and drop como no exemplo no site do jquery:
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Peguei a mesma lógica do script de exemplo e apliquei numa página HTML, onde eu posso alterar a ordem dos conteúdos(div content) dentro do body, porém eu gostaria de diminuir o tamanho da div para facilitar o posicionamento do elemento, pensei em detectar o evento ondrag e assim diminuir o elemento, porém queria ver uma forma dinâmica de chamar o evento, que o evento esteja sujeito a qualquer tag filha do body.

Comment: Pesquisa por draggable, ondragend, ondragstart, ondrag, ondragenter, ondragleave e outros similares. A primeira vez que implementei deu um pouco de trabalho, nas vezes seguintes já foi mais de boa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez essa não seja a melhor maneira, mas na documentação tem a referencia do `sortable` https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-activate

Seria algo como: `$( ".selector" ).on( "sortactivate", function( event, ui ) {} );`

Mas eu fiz pegando a classe auxiliar *helper* pelo CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que não aplica a classe no `click` só no `drag`

O que eu fiz é que quando o elemento está no estado `sortable` o `jquery.ui` aplica uma classe nele chamada `ui-sortable-helper`, ai eu fui no CSS e coloquei um estilo nessa classe e funcionou como eu queria

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> -->
<style>
    #sortable1,
    #sortable2 {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        width: 142px;
        min-height: 20px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 0 0 0;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #sortable1 li,
    #sortable2 li {
        margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        width: 120px;
    }

    .ui-sortable-helper {
        background-color: red;
        transform: scale(0.7)
    }

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable()
})

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="sortable1">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou!

Comment: @AdryanAlencar sem problemas meu caro!